# persistentvolumeclaim "jenkins-volume-claim" not found

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

In my minikube I'm getting an error `persistentvolumeclaim "jenkins-volume-claim" not found`

I'm installing jenkins using helm with the command below:

```
helm install --name jenkins -f kubernetes/jenkins-values.yaml stable/jenkins --namespace jenkins-system
```

the snippet about `Persistence` in `jenkins-values.yaml` is below:

```
Persistence:
  Enabled: true
  ## A manually managed Persistent Volume and Claim
  ## Requires Persistence.Enabled: true
  ## If defined, PVC must be created manually before volume will be bound
  ExistingClaim: jenkins-volume-claim
```

I've created a persistence volume using the command below:

```
kubectl create -f persistence.yaml
```

persistence.yaml looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: jenkins-volume
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /data/jenkins-volume/
```

**Question**

I have persistence volume `jenkins-volume` created but am still getting error `persistentvolumeclaim "jenkins-volume-claim" not found`. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

The error message points to missing `PersistentVolumeClaim` named `jenkins-volume-claim`. To create one, execute:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> create -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: jenkins-volume-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
EOF
```

Executing after that `kubectl get pv` should show the `jenkins-volume` PV in `Bound` status (assuming the PV has been created already with capacity of at least 5Gi).

Use selector(s) as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#selector) to make sure the claim will bind to the desired pre-created PV (persistent volume) in case there are more than one PV available with proper capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line,

```
## If defined, PVC must be created manually before volume will be bound
ExistingClaim: jenkins-volume-claim
```

So, you have to `PersistentVolumeClaim` not `PersistentVolume` with name `jenkins-volume-claim`.

See what is `PersistentVolumeClaim` from here: [PersistentVolumeClaims](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)